# How does character representation in array index work in this case?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm a beginner in C and I have code like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i;
    int ndigit[10] = { [9] = 5 };
    printf("%d\n",++ndigit['9']);
}
```

This prints the value something like this :

```
-1074223011
```

But when I change the statement to:

```
++ndigit['9'-'0']
```

It is correctly printing the value

```
6
```

I wonder why there is a need for adding `-0` in my index to make it work properly? And why just mentioning `++ndigit['9']`, doesn't help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `'9' != 9`. `'9' == 57`.

Comment: '9' need not be equal to 57. In either case ndigit is being redeclared so that code won't compile.

Comment: Need not be, but unless this code's running on an EBCDIC or some embedded system, it is.

Comment: Hi , any body tell me what "int ndigit[10] = { [9] = 5 };" means? I didnt have seen such a statement

Comment: @rakeshNS google designated initializers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to access the 10th element in an array, you do:

```
array[9]
```

If you want to access the element at the index which has the value of the character constant for the number `9` + 1, you do:

```
array['9']
```

Due to the way ASCII (and all other character encoding schemes used by C, see Wiz's comment) is defined, the expression `'9' - '0'` actually equals 9, which might confuse you in this case.

Comment: Actually, every character-encoding scheme that is used by C, '9'-'0' must equal 9. The standard guarantees that: "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous." (The list it's talking about is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).

Comment: why does this code execute and give a result?... Its trying to access some out of bound memory area right? it should crash before that isnt it?

Comment: @NOOB: It does, that does not mean it will crash. It's "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @Ant's: I think NOOB's referring to the out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: @NOOB: `Its trying to access some out of bound memory area ` How your saying so? As per the answer given, `'9'`-`'0'` should return `9` and yes I can access it within the array index know?

Comment: i was mentionig about this use ndigit['9'] . This i considered as an out of boundary array access.